# Move the exe out of the dist folder and make it work?

Tags: python, dependencies, exe, pyinstaller, lib

I'd like to generate an .exe file with --onedir and move the generated exe out of the dist folder to elsewhere (e.g. Desktop) and set up some absolute path to the dist folder so that the .exe can still work properly.

I've tried things such as, set up the Python env or the load library inside the python script to the Dist folder, but, nothing worked so far. I also looked into the manual but I couldn't find anything relevant regarding this issue.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Comment: @mad_ yes, " Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\JRuivoW\Desktop\cmder\myWenv\build_env\compiled_files\dist\python35.dll'.

LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found. "

Answer (score 2):

You can just make a shortcut to your .exe file. Keep the folder in your C drive or anywhere you want it, but right click on the .exe and select create shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

The `--onedir` parameter creates a folder containing all your exe needs to run. You need to move the entire folder elsewhere, not just the .exe, because that's how it works.

If you want everything contained in a single exe, use `--onefile` instead. This would increase the size of your exe, but you would have to deal with only one file instead of a dir, easing portability.